# Generic Extension Method with Concrete Class Override

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, c#-7.0

I have a third party DLL that returns objects like `Customers`, `Orders`, etc. I'll call them `Your Entities`. They do have a common `IYourEntity` interface so I can use that as a source constraint.

I want to create a generic conversion extension method to convert all these different third party entities to `My Entities` with some streamlined and more maintainable code.

....but I can't figure out how to make a generic extension method that will call the concrete extension method for the specific conversion of each class.

Putting some of the main aspects of my code below, but you can get a full fiddle to play with [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbiLQh).

Yes, I'm probably showing I'm a bit clueless on how to do this and maybe trying to combine different concepts. Any pointers much appreciated as I've been beating my head for a couple of days now and need a life line :)

```
public interface IYourEntity
{
    int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public interface IConvertToMyEntity<TYourEntity, TMyEntity>
    where TYourEntity : class, IYourEntity, new()
    where TMyEntity : class, IMyEntity, new()
{
    TMyEntity ToMyEntity(TYourEntity yourEntity);
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static IMyEntity ToMyEntity(this IYourEntity yourEntity)
    {
        return new MyEntity1();
    }

    public static List<IMyEntity> ToMyEntityList(this List<IYourEntity> lstYourEntities)
    {
        return lstYourEntities.ConvertAll(q => q.ToMyEntity());
    }
}

public class YourEntity1 : IYourEntity, IConvertToMyEntity<YourEntity1, MyEntity1>
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string YourEntityName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyEntity1 ToMyEntity(YourEntity1 yourEntity)
    {
        return new MyEntity1()
        {Id = yourEntity.Id, MyEntityName = yourEntity.YourEntityName, CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow};
    }

    public List<MyEntity1> ToMyEntityList(List<YourEntity1> lstYourEntities)
    {
        return lstYourEntities.ConvertAll(q => ToMyEntity(q));
    }
}
```

Comment: You said `YourEntity`s are coming from a third party DLL, but it seems they are coupled to `MyEntity`s through the `IConvertToMyEntity` interface. Could you please explain what exactly is under your control?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara yes, they are from a third party. I tried to create the IConvertToMyEntity interface in attempts to solve this problem, but maybe that approach is not correct. My goal is to be able to do this in a generic method for converting any list of third party objects I retrieve from this third party. i.e. `List<IYourEntity> lstYourEntities.ToMyEntities()` which will call an entity type specific conversion method to get a list of my entities.

Comment: Just take the easy way out and use automapper.  Regardless you're going to need to use the same property names or create a manual map for the ones that don't match, and if thats the case then just use auto mapper its meant for it

Comment: @johnny5 yes, I can use AutoMapper for the nuts and bolts of copying the data, but the hard part here is how to create a generic method that will know which maps to use.

Comment: crichavin, I don't understand why thats a hard part.  1. You know what type you're trying to adapt to and from.  e.g in your example `YourEntity1, MyEntity1` just take in `IAdaptable<YourEntity,MyEntity>` and where ever you need it just call convert.

Comment: @johnny5.....first I'll say it's hard for me....cause I'm not that bright in this area, lol... but I think I see what you're saying. Something like: `List<IMyEntity> lstMyEntities = Mapper.Map<IMyEntity>(lstYourEntity1)` and it will know which specific type `lstIYourEntity1` is and use the appropriate map? Am I getting warmer? (like I said, I'm a bit dim :)

Comment: @johnny5 Tried here, but got stuck: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pAuFkP

Comment: You need to simplify your code and use SOLID principles, e.g Single Responsibility, `IConvertToMyEntity<YourEntity1, MyEntity1>` Your class should not inherit from this, instead a mapper and just call map on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the classes implementing `IYourEntity` are from a third party and not under your control, you can't implement an own `IConvertToMyEntity<T1, T2>` interface upon these.

One way you can handle it is by overloads of such conversion (extension) methods.
There's no need for any generic `T` type arguments; the common `IYourEntity` interface suffices.

Suppose you have 3 classes implementing the `IYourEntity` interface;
e.g. `YourCustomer`, `YourOrder` and `YourProduct`.

These need to be converted to `IMyEntity` instances, of which you might have different concrete implementations;
e.g. a general `MyEntity` and a specific `MyProduct`.

For the conversion you set up an extension method targeting `IYourEntity`.
This extension method will be called to convert an `IYourEntity` to an `IMyEntity` in case a more specific overload of this extension method does not exist.

```
public static IMyEntity ToMyEntity(this IYourEntity target)
{
     return new MyEntity { Id = target.Id, EntityName = "Fallback name" };
}
```

For the entities that require a custom conversion, you set up overloads of this extension method targeting those specific source class types.
Below are such ones for `YourOrder` and `YourProduct` (but not for `YourCustomer`).

```
public static IMyEntity ToMyEntity(this YourOrder target)
{
    return new MyEntity { Id = target.Id, EntityName = target.OrderName.ToUpper() };
}

public static IMyEntity ToMyEntity(this YourProduct target)
{
    return new MyProduct { Id = target.Id * 100, EntityName = target.ProductName };
}
```

Next, define the extension method to convert the list of `IYourEntity` instances to a list of `IMyEntity` instances. In the code below, the inbetween cast to `dynamic` enables that the appropriate `ToMyEntity` overload will be called.

*Note that the `ToMyEntity` methods don't have to be extension methods, but it might be convenient to have these in place in case you need to convert a single instance instead of a list.*

```
public static List<IMyEntity> ToMyEntities(this List<IYourEntity> target)
{
    var myEntities  = new List<IMyEntity>();

    foreach (var yourEntity in target)
    {
        var myEntity = Extensions.ToMyEntity((dynamic)yourEntity);
        myEntities.Add(myEntity);
    }

    return myEntities;
}
```

---

An example - [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/np9FSI)

```
var yourEntities = new List<IYourEntity>()
{
    new YourCustomer() { Id = 1 },
    new YourOrder() { Id = 2, OrderName = "Order-2"},
    new YourProduct() { Id = 3, ProductName = "Product-3"}
 };

var myEnties = yourEntities.ToMyEntities();

myEnties.ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}  ({2})", 
    o.Id, o.EntityName, o.GetType().Name
));
```

The output of the example above looks like below.
Notice how the `YourCustomer` instance was handled by the general `IYourEntity` conversion, whereas the `YourOrder` and `YourProduct` instances got a specific treatment.

```
1 - Fallback name  (MyEntity)
2 - ORDER-2  (MyEntity)
300 - Product-3  (MyProduct)
```

Comment: This seems very promising...looking at it in more detail now.

Comment: Thank you. This looks great and was just what I was looking for. I didn't know you could have overrides like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your extension method to this:

```cs
    private static IMyEntity ToMyEntity(this IYourEntity yourEntity)
    {
        if (yourEntity is IConvertToMyEntity<IYourEntity, IMyEntity> convertible)
            return convertible.ToMyEntity;
        return new MyEntity1();
    }
```

This will not work in most cases unless you also make your interface co- and contra-variant:

```cs
public interface IConvertToMyEntity<in TYourEntity, out TMyEntity>
    where TYourEntity : class, IYourEntity, new()
    where TMyEntity : class, IMyEntity, new()
{
    TMyEntity ToMyEntity(TYourEntity yourEntity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still not completely clear to me how you can make a third party class implements `IConvertToMyEntity` that easily. Assuming you did this only to show us your actual goal, you should be very careful with what you are trying to accomplish in the `Main`.

If you use a `List<IYourEntity>`, you can only use methods and properties defined in the interface, unless you know what you are doing with specific cast. The need for `List<IYourEntity>` or `List<IMyEntity>` limits a lot the implementation of a custom mapper between `My` classes and `Your` classes. Here a possible solution:

As I said, I did not change `Your` classes:

```
public interface IYourEntity
{
    int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class YourEntity1 : IYourEntity
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string YourEntityName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Also `My` classes are very simple and do not contain any logic for the mapping. This is a debatable choice, but I generally prefer to keep conversion logic separated from the classes involved. This helps to maintain clean your code in case you have several conversion functions for the same pair of classes. By the way, here they are:

```
public interface IMyEntity
{
    int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MyEntity1 : IMyEntity
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MyEntityName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And this is how I designed the custom converter

```
public interface IMyEntityConverter
{
    IMyEntity Convert(IYourEntity yourEntity);
}

public class MyEntity1Converter : IMyEntityConverter
{
    public IMyEntity Convert(IYourEntity yourEntity) 
    {
        var castedYourEntity = yourEntity as YourEntity1;
        return new MyEntity1() 
        {
            Id = castedYourEntity.Id, 
            MyEntityName = castedYourEntity.YourEntityName, 
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
    }
}
```

It is clear the lack of genericity, but you cannot do otherwise if you need an extension method on a `List` of generic `My` and `Your` classes. Also tried with  covariant and contravariant interfaces but C# does not let you use them with this implementation.

Now the core of the solution: you need something that binds `Your` class to the `My` class with a custom converter, and all of this should be as more transparent as possible.

```
public class EntityAdapter<YourType, MyType>
    where YourType : IYourEntity
    where MyType : IMyEntity
{
    protected YourType wrappedEntity;
    protected IMyEntityConverter converter;
        
    public EntityAdapter(YourType wrappedEntity, IMyEntityConverter converter) 
    {
        this.wrappedEntity = wrappedEntity;
        this.converter = converter;
    }
    
    public static implicit operator YourType(EntityAdapter<YourType, MyType> entityAdapter) => entityAdapter.wrappedEntity;
    public static explicit operator MyType(EntityAdapter<YourType, MyType> entityAdapter) => 
        (MyType) entityAdapter.converter.Convert(entityAdapter.wrappedEntity);
        
    public MyType CastToMyEntityType()
    {
        return (MyType) this;
    }
}
```

The pseudo-transparency here is given by the implicit cast to `Your` class. The advantage is that you can cast this `EntityAdapter` to an instance of a `My` class by calling `CastToMyEntityType` or the explicit operator overload.

The painful part is with the extension methods:

```
public static class EntityAdapterExtensions
{
    public static List<IMyEntity> ToIMyEntityList(this List<EntityAdapter<IYourEntity, IMyEntity>> lstEntityAdapters)
    {
        return lstEntityAdapters.ConvertAll(e => e.CastToMyEntityType());
    }
    
    public static List<EntityAdapter<IYourEntity, IMyEntity>> ToEntityAdapterList(this List<IYourEntity> lstYourEntities)
    {
        return lstYourEntities.Select(e => 
        {                    
            switch (e)
            {
                case YourEntity1 yourEntity1:
                    return new EntityAdapter<IYourEntity, IMyEntity>(yourEntity1, new MyEntity1Converter());
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("You forgot to map " + e.GetType());
            }
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The first one is pretty straightforward to understand, but the second one is definitely something that require maintenance. I gave up on generics for the reasons already explained, so the only thing left to do is to create the `EntityAdapter`s starting from the actual entity types.

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uLnWOG)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little controversial but maybe a different way is better?

Firstly, and this is more for my sake, I would suggest more easily understandable terminology so instead of 'your' and 'my' I would use 'source' and 'dest'.

Secondly I wonder if the generics route is necessary? I'm assuming (and I may be wrong) that for each of the classes you have coming from your third-party assembly, you have a specific class for it to be converted to. So maybe this could be achieved much more easily with a constructor override in your destination class.

```
// third party class example
public class SourceClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// the destination class in your project
public class DestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    // default constructor
    public DestClass()
    {
    }

    // conversion constructor
    public DestClass(SourceClass source)
    {
        Id = source.Id;
        Name = source.Name;
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

This way you convert a single instance using:

```
// source being an instance of the third-party class
DestClass myInstance = new DestClass(source);
```

And you can convert a list with LINQ:

```
// source list is IList<SourceClass>
IList<DestClass> myList = sourceList.Select(s => new DestClass(s)).ToList();
```

If you wanted to you could implement extensions for your conversions. This again would not be generic as you'll need one for each class pairing but as it's an alternative to writing a converter class for each, it will be overall less code.

```
public static class SourceClassExtensions
{
    public static DestClass ToDest(this SourceClass source)
        => new DestClass(source);

    public static IList<DestClass> ToDest(this IList<SourceClass> source)
        => source.Select(s => new DestClass(s)).ToList();
}
```

If you still want something generic then you'll want a converter for each class pair, implementing a suitable interface. Then I'd recommend a converter factory class where you'll need to register the specific converters either into a dictionary in the class or via dependency injection. I can go into this further if you'd prefer but I think it would be more complicated.

Comment: Yes, I like your use of `Source` and `Destination` better :) The reason I wanted generics was to streamline code and try to eliminate a switch statement based on `Source` to carry out the rest of the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for writing here its not an actual answer,

there is no option for generically to do this

you have to write for every entity

```
public interface IConvertToMyEntity<TYourEntity, TMyEntity>
    where TYourEntity : class, IYourEntity, new()
    where TMyEntity : class, IMyEntity, new()
{
    TMyEntity ToMyEntity(TYourEntity yourEntity);
}
```

I saw this code from your question.

It depends on what you want to do after transformation

you should use data mapper

```
public class MapProfile : Profile
{
    public MapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TYourEntity , TMyEntity >();
        CreateMap<TMyEntity , TYourEntity >();
    }
}
```